# reference Configuration files

Tags: playframework

Is a location that I can get the reference configuration files from, wholly?

In the documentation there are bits and pieces and instructions for changing specific settings - but I am unable to find them (via the documentation) in whole.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Play's `reference.conf` is located [here](https://github.com/playframework/playframework/blob/2.7.x/core/play/src/main/resources/reference.conf) in its GitHub repository.